# To convert an application which uses ActiveX controls to a browser independent application

Tags: com, frameworks, cross-browser, activex

I am given an application which uses ActiveX controls and communicates with COM components and makes a video call.

As it works only in IE i am asked to convert the application into a browser independent one(which implies support more number of browsers).

Can anyone suggest me what any useful alternatives? 
(The application is used to make video calls and it uses spark)

Someone suggested me firebreath framework. Is it useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [FireBreath](http://www.firebreath.org); FireBreath plugins act both as ActiveX controls and NPAPI plugins, so if you port to FireBreath it will work everywhere.